# A question on parallelizability

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Is there  a manifold $M$ such that for every $x\in M$, $M-\{x\}$ is not parallelizable but there is  a  finite set $S\subset M$, with $\# S>1$,  such that $M-S$ is  parallelizable?

Comment: The question presupposes that $M$ is connected; otherwise, the answer would trivially be yes.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks for the comment. I think you consider the disjoint union of two sphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: any finite set $S \subset M$ can be contained in the interior of an embedded closed disc in $M$, and cutting this out gives a manifold diffeomorphic to $M - \{x\}$. So if $M - S$ were parallelisable, $M-\{x\}$ would be too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why a manifold is smoothly n -homogeneous?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/91591/automorphism-of-smooth-manifolds/ : in the answers to this question you will find arguments that show that the diffeomorphism group acts $n$-transitively on the manifold.